# What is responsebody in retrofit?

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit

I am new to retrofit and I know to send serialized objects to and from the server.

Earlier I used to create java objects and use gson for converting.

What is `ResponseBody` used for?

What does the below text mean?

> A one-shot stream from the origin server to the client application with the raw bytes of the  * response body. Each response body is
> supported by an active connection to the webserver. This  * imposes
> both obligations and limits on the client application.

```
@Headers("Authorization: Key=$SERVER_KEY", "Content-Type:$CONTENT_TYPE")
    @POST("fcm/send")
    suspend fun postNotification(@Body notification: NotificationData): Response<ResponseBody>
```

The above code is what I am trying to understand

Answer (score 2):

This actually is a good question.

The documentation says it very clearly:

> This class may be used to stream very **large responses**. For example, it is possible to use this class to read a response that is larger than the entire memory allocated to the current process. It can even stream a response larger than the **total storage on the current device**, which is a common requirement for **video streaming applications**.
>
> Because this class does not buffer the full response in memory, the
> application may not re-read the bytes of the response. Use this one
> shot to read the entire response into memory with bytes or string. Or
> **stream the response with either source, byteStream, or charStream**.

In resume, is a `model` class used for big responses that have to be cut in little pieces of data, as documentation says used for example for video streaming applications.

It's like a `socket`, an open connection that don't download all the data directly to the device to don't over consume the memory, you can split this information.

Don't forget to close the `Response` after using it:

```
Response.body().close()
```

Link to documentation: https://square.github.io/okhttp/4.x/okhttp/okhttp3/-response-body/

Comment: I understood that it is used for really large data, but isn't splitting up of data into small parts the work of the server? Why should we do it in application level?

Comment: You can't adapt your server to each device that use your app, some will have more RAM than others , so as a server, you send the data, and the app will consume it, so in this case, the data will be a stream and we will use it as needed in the app, I don't know if I explain myself.